# Laravel 4 - Many-to-Many with timestamps OR Many-to-One with history

Tags: php, laravel-4, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have a bit of a mind boggling question.

The scenario:
I have an Order that needs to move from Process to Process.  One order can only be in One Process at a time, but One Process can have Many Orders in it at any given time.

But then I also need a history of when the Order landed in which Process.

Somehow I can't get my mind around this, so if anyone can give me an idea of which direction you'd trot in, I would appreciate it very much.

---

I did notice when I created Departments for my Users, in my department_user table where I added the timestamps(), it doesn't actually update those timestamps when a new relationship is created between a user and a department.  Is there any way to get that working?  'cause I'm thinking these two issues are very much related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might set up your `orders` table to have a column `process_id` and then set up the relationship as:

```
class Order extends Eloquent
{
    public function process()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Process');
    }
}

class Process extends Eloquent
{
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Order');
    }
}
```

Regarding the order/process history, I would write that to a separate history table when moving the Order to a new Process.

```
class OrderProcessHistory extends Eloquent
{
    protected $fillable = array(
        'order_id',
        'process_id'
    );

    protected $timestamps = true;
}
```

Then just something like...

`OrderProcessHistory::create(array('order_id' => $order->id, 'process_id' => $process->id));`

Comment: Thanx. So the history table would have a order_id and process_id and date_created, and I just write to it whenever I change the process manually?  It would be nice if that could happen automatically.

Comment: Just added something more along those lines, yeah!